# How to wrap callback-function to get promise in WinJS?

Tags: javascript, winjs, promise, asynccallback

I wonder how I can achieve a conversion such as:

```
fn(args, function (errors, results) {})
```

to

```
fn(args).then(function (results){})
```

by simply calling something like

```
makePromise(fn, args).then(function (results))
```

in **WinJS**.

Background: I have a predefined interface using async callbacks, but I'd like to use them as a promise.

Is this possible in this way? Maybe even directly supported by WinJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I could not find such a method in the [official docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211867.aspx). However, this should do it:

```
function makePromise(fn, args) {
    return new WinJS.Promise(function init(completeDispatch, errorDispatch) {
        fn(args, function handler(errors, results) {
            if (errors)
                errorDispatch(errors);
            else
                completeDispatch(results);
         });
    });
}
```

Comment: This is a good basic example. Note though, that you will lose any function scope, so you will want to bind any function using this. Something like: `makePromise(fn.bind(this), args).then( ... );` Also, this only works if the function passed in accepts a single argument.

Comment: Yes, this does loose *context* and further arguments, but I thought the OP didn't need those. It would unnecessarily complicate the example as well :-)

Comment: Sure, I'm just mentioning it in case it trips up anyone. This example works for the direct case above.